# get backups form stolen phone

Tags: lost-phone, imei

my phone samsung SM G361H had stolen while travelling.

any possibility to locate it.

Any possibility to get the backup of contact numbers , photos saved in it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Google Security](http://security.google.com)
Normally theirs a google service running in background and youre able to find lock or delete your phone. And its a little bit to late for a backup.